Indexing Box for Fluting Columns
Does anyone know how to build an indexing wheel/box to flute columns? I'm trying to learn to make my own columns for neoclassical-inspired projects.

You're an experienced SEer, can you outline the research you did prior to asking the Question? Because there are indeed guides to indexing turned components out there.....
